# Lookup price based on quantity in a price brackets between two tabs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a table to lookup the price based on a quantity in a certain bracket in another table, on another tab.  I thought i wanted a Vlookup with some sort of other nested formula but getting unstuck as there is a quantity range in my ratecard.

[image: Customer Cost]

So I need a formula for the pink cell (E16) to tell me how the unit cost based on the qty in Cell C16 and using the pricing card (See below snapshot)[image: Ratecard]

Comment: You can use a formula to do this, refer to this site: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4782-excel-vlookup-between-two-values.html Once you have a working formula, post it here as an answer. If you get stuck, update your post with what you have tried and the formula you have along with what is not working.

Comment: So Unit Cost on 62.5 would be 7 rather than 5?  The lookup table is only relevant to New Employees or all three types of employee?

Answer (score 0):

try this, should work, assuming your second sheet is called "Ratecard". If not, please change the sheet name in the reference accordingly.

```
=INDEX(Ratecard!$F$18:$F$24,MATCH(C16,Ratecard!$D$18:$D$24,1))
```

The "1" at the end of the formula will do the trick.